# Unable to update character set of mysql from utf8mb4 to utf8

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I am running mysql  Ver 8.0.20.

Currently the collation and character sets are set to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and

[image]

[image]

I have been trying to update these to UTF8 by running these commands. But everytime I close the client and log back in the values have reverted to utf8mb4.

```
SET character_set_client = 'utf8';
SET character_set_connection = 'utf8';
SET character_set_database = 'latin1';
SET character_set_filesystem = 'binary';
SET character_set_results = 'utf8';
SET character_set_server = 'latin1';
SET character_set_system = 'utf8';

set collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';
set collation_database = 'latin1_swedish_ci';
set collation_database = 'latin1_swedish_ci'

commit;

ALTER DATABASE sanskvrcpu_db2 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

The output of these statmentnts is something like this:

```
mysql> ALTER DATABASE sanskvrcpu_db2 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 3719): 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.
Warning (Code 3778): 'utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate collation instead.
```

Comment: Why would you want to limit yourself to UTF8? UTF8MB4 is a superset of UTF8.

Comment: Also note that *utf8* is going to be an alias for *utf8mb4* in the [future](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. `SET ...` applies to the current "session" (aka "connection").  So the information is lost when you disconnect.
2. `SET GLOBAL ...` applies to the global variables, but not the current session.  It applies only to new connections.  But they are lost when the server goes down.  When doing item 3, also do item 2.
3. Changing the config file (`my.cnf` or whatever) applies after the next restart.  When doing item 2, also do item 3.
4. MySQL 8.0 has `SET PERSIST`, a way of "persisting" global settings via item 2 without resorting to also doing item 3.  Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

(You did item 1.)

Exception:  Some settings are both 'session' and 'global'; hence the above restrictions are not quite followed.